# How to make a div absolute to another absolute div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want the elements inside .bannerinner class to be in the exact middle alignment of the .banner class but it doesn't really work that way. I'm open to any advices, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks from now.

I have this .banner class "absolute" to my "relative" background

```
.banner {
   background-color: rgba(209, 29, 155, 0.212);
   padding: 8px 15px;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 10vh;
   width: 150vh;
   max-height: 10vh;
   min-height: 10vh;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 9vh;
}
```

and also inside this .banner class there is a .bannerinner class

```
.bannerinner {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   left: 2vh;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 50%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: do you want to center `.bannerinner` inside `.banner`?

Comment: Yes, i want .bannerinner in the exact center of the .banner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.innerbanner` to `left:50%` and `top:50%`. This puts the upper left corner of `.innerbanner` to the center of `.banner`.

Then transform `.innerbanner` back to -50% of its own width and height. This sets the center of `.innerbanner` exactly to the center of `.banner`.

See code example:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 2vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(209, 29, 155, 0.212);
}

.bannerinner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <p>Background: relative</p>
  <div class="banner">
    <p>Banner: absolute </p>
    <div class="bannerinner">
      <p>Inner Banner: absolute</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that transform (translate) thing saved it all.